# python dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I have the below dictionaries within a list:

```
price_list = [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '100', 'year': '2000', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2022', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '1220', 'year': '160', 'currency': 'eur'},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2080', 'currency': 'eur'}
]
```

The below code calculates the average price of the list:

```
for d in price_list:
    for _,item in d.items():
        total += int(d['price'])
        count += 1
        print(total,count)
        print('average=', total / count)
```

I want to be able to ignore anything within 10 years of the mid. So if i had an input of year = 2020, when querying against my list i will only want search back to 2010 and anything forward to 2030. Is this possible to implement?

Comment: What does calculating the average have to do with your question? Or did you mean that you want to include only the items within +-10 years of a given year in the average calculation?

Comment: That is right, i am able to calculate the average across tho whole timeframe. I want to limit this to -/+ 10years. Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well, what you're currently doing is adding up the prices for *all* items and counting them all. What could you do to check `if` a specific `d` has a `'price'` that's `>=` some year `- 10` `and` `<=` some year `+ 10`? What if you only counted it and added it to the total under that condition?

Comment: You have a bunch of other issues with this code. You're not just adding up the prices of all the items. You're adding the price of the item to your sum not just once, but once for every entry in the dictionary representing the item.

Comment: And then, since you are storing your prices as strings, when you add them you won't get the numerical sum of the prices. For example, '200' + '200' is '200200', not 400.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the year and test it for the year range, then if it is an 'apple' then add the price so you calculate the average.

```
l = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '100', 'year': '2000', 'currency': 'eur'},    {'id': 2, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2022', 'currency': 'eur'},    {'id': 3, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '1220', 'year': '160', 'currency': 'eur'},    {'id': 4, 'name': 'apple', 'price': '150', 'year': '2080', 'currency': 'eur'}]

mid_year = 2020

total = 0
count = 0
for d in l:
    if int(d['year']) >= mid_year-10 and int(d['year']) <= mid_year+10:
        if d['name'] == 'apple':
            total += int(d['price'])
            count += 1

print('average=', total / count)
```

Runnable code: https://trinket.io/python3/1ab1232e44

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short `for` to make it one line

```
price = [int(d['price']) for d in price_list if int(d['year'])>year-10 and int(d['year'])<year+10]
print('average=', sum(price)/len(price)
```